# Javascript reduce() - What does the return line do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I understand that it does reduce () in the most basic examples but not in one like this, especially the return line. It would be great if someone could explain how it works or put a more understandable example that returns the same result.

```
var line = 'abazzzzax'
var obj = line.split('').reduce(function(p, c){
    return (p[c] = ++p[c] || 1, p);
}, {});
console.log(obj)
// Output => { a: 3, b: 1, z: 4, x: 1 }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: The return line does lots of things. Which part don't you understand? Is it one of the operators?

Comment: The real question is why people use reduce everywhere even if its not really useful (like in this case)

Comment: The issue here is not using reduce, but writing too smart code. I suspect that this is a showoff. If author of that snippet would been aiming for maximum performance, then He'd use loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner part of the function can be rewritten like this:

```
var obj = line.split('').reduce(function(p, c){
    if (!p[c]) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        ++p[c];
    }
    return p;
}, {});
```

Splitting out this expression:

`p[c] = ++p[c] || 1`

When `p[c]` doesn't exist yet, then the values is `undefined`. `++(undefined)` returns `NaN` which is a falsy statement, so the value of `p[c]` will be 1. When `p[c]` does exist, then the value is incremented and then assigned back on to itself. Something like `i = ++i`, which is a little confusing in my opinion.

Finally, the comma operator allows you to run expressions in sequence from left to right, so the final expression is returned, which is the `p` object that keeps track of the occurrences.

Comment: I think `++p[c];` is supposed to be `p[c]  = ++p[c];`

Comment: @sushanth that doesnt make a difference, does it?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to be.

Comment: My bad. I just zoned out !

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function takes in 2 arguments in this example.

`p`  --> The initial state which is `{}`

`c`  --> the value of each iteration `a` , `b` , `a` .....

```
p[c] = ++p[c] || 1 //If the `key` is already available we increment it by 1 or set it to 1.
```

So we first update it and return the `p` which contains the updated object, which is due to the comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

It counts occurrences of each character in the string.

It's basically

```
if accumulator[character] exists, increase number stored in accumulator[character] by 1 (this happens if we have set it already to 1, somewhere in the past, because otherwise it will not exist)
else set accumulator[character] to 1 (this happens when we notice a first character of a new kind)
return accumulator object
```